# How to display a phtml file on all pages in magento. my design layout is 2columns-right

Tags: xml, magento, layout, php

display a phtml file on all pages in magento. my design layout is 2columns-left

I have tried placing that block in left side in page.xml

Comment: You can find this in proper way here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449832/magento-create-a-fixed-block-in-all-pages

Answer (score 0):

you can try this below code... If phtml file path is your package>you template>template>page>noleft.phtml

```
    <block type="core/template" name="home.ht.leftnav" after="currency" 
template="page/noleft.phtml"/>
```

Comment: -i want to display this phtml on all pages and on left side..
<block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnavigation" template="catalog/navigation/left_nav.phtml"/>

thanks for reply @amit bera

Comment: `<block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnavigation" template="catalog/navigation/left_nav.phtml"/>`

Comment: Do you want to display some sort of category navigation on leftsidebar through out on your website ?

Comment: i have already created category navigation and displayed on home page, but issue is to display that left navigation all pages

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display leftsidebar Category Navigation on your website try below code:

```
<reference name="left">
            <!-- Left Categories Navigation Begin-->
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnavigation" template="catalog/navigation/left_nav.phtml"/>
            <!-- Left Categories Navigation End-->
        </reference>
```